# etherwallet-3.4.1/ on private chain setup - having 404 error

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes, nodejs, myetherwallet

I am following the [MyEtherWallet: Use Your Own Server Guide](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/226) to use MyEtherWallet on my private ethereum network. I am doing this setup on my node, where my ethereum node runs.

I have done first 4 steps.

In `response.js` file: I have set host as:

```
host: '127.0.0.1'
```

In `runLocalServer.js` file: I have set `app.use` as:

```
app.use(vhost('127.0.0.1', require('./index.js').app));
```

Since port 80 is occupied, I have changed port number 80 to my free port number as 8000;

- `httpServer.listen(80);` in `runLocalServer.js`.
- `httpServer.listen(80);` in `runServer.js`

As recommended on Step-2 I run:

```
[~]$ node runLocalServer.js
//waits
```

But on Step-3, when I navigate to http://localhost/api.mew inside my node, I do have 404 or timeout errors. I was not able to end up on a empty/white page.

I was not able to figure out how to overcome this problem or where I am doing something wrong/missing. Any valuable guidance will be appreciated.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you changed port from 80 to 8000, you need to navigate to  http://localhost:8000/api.mew

Also later when changing `SERVERURL` you should put the same http://localhost:8000/api.mew

Please note that currently [Use Your Own Server Guide](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/226) does not correspond with recent release (3.4.2):

- you need to change addresses in `nodeIP.json`, not `response.js`
- when changing `etherwallet-master.js` it is easier to search for `rpc.myetherwallet.com` to get the line with `SERVERURL`

---

You can serve both `api.mew` and `index.html` from single port. Just edit `json_relay_node/index.js` and add `app.use(express.static('../dist'));`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static('../dist'));
app.get('/api.mew', function(req, res) {
    wait.launchFiber(handleRequest, req, res);
});
app.post('/api.mew', function(req, res) {
    wait.launchFiber(handleRequest, req, res);
});
```

Comment: It works one small question. As ip address I used: 127.0.0.1. I can only open `index.html` inside my local machine. But later on can I do something like: <mydomain>:8000/index.html using nodejs? for clients to reach the website.

Comment: Yep, you need to change `SERVERURL` in `etherwallet-master.js` to <domain>:8000/api.mew and ensure that port 8000 is accessible from internet.

Comment: Changed Line: `mewServer.prototype.SERVERURL = "http://<my_ip>:8000/api.mew";`  I replaced `127.0.0.1` with my server's IP address in `nodeIP.json` and I do face with following error when I try to navigate into `http://<my_ip>:8000/index.html` error: `Cannot GET /index.html` and navigate into `http://<my_ip>:8000/api.mew` error: `Cannot GET /api.mew`

Comment: Please note that port 8000 is accessible from internet.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. You need to serve index.html and etherwallet-master.js separately. E.g. with nginx or `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. In this case you need two ports: one to serve `api.mew` and another one to serve `index.html`. Another option is to rewrite `runLocalServer.js` to serve both.

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't `http://<my_ip>:8000/api.mew` return an empty page like in `http://localhost:8000/api.mew` instead of `Cannot GET /api.mew`.

Comment: I also updated `app.use(vhost('<my_ip>', require('./index.js').app));`  in `runLocalServer.js` and blank page show up for `http://<my_ip>:8000/api.mew` (please ignore my previous comment). Do you have any suggestion about to re-write `runLocalServer.js` to serve but since I only have one port available.

Comment: Thank you very much everything works under your guidance. But I do get following message from `node runLocalServer.js` => `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect'` when I refresh the website on `http://<my_ip>:8000` .

Comment: seems like it can't find your eth node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51414/discussion-between-avatar-and-max-taldykin).