# etherwallet-3.4.2 on private chain invalid sender error

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, myetherwallet

In order to use `etherwallet` in private chain setup, I completed following [Use Your Own Server Guide](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/226), [answer_1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11227/4575) and  [answer_2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11240/4575). I have added `Custom Node` and `MyEtherWallet` works , except sometimes it requires refreshing the page if there is disconnection with the node.

As an example, I can see my correct account balance, where I verified the value also in `geth`.

[image]

When I tried to send a transaction to a valid account address on my private blockchain, I have faced with the following error: `invalid sender`.

[Q] What may be the reason of this error and how can I fix it? I am able to complete this `transaction` inside `geth`.

[image]

Comment: Please, use the `myetherwallet` tag for the underlying software. the `ethereum-wallet-dapp` tag refers to the wallet used by the mist browser. Thanks! :-)

Comment: are you using chainId 1 on your private network or do you have a different chainId? do the same setup with EIP155 off and let us know how it goes

Comment: Ah I feel like stupid, On the window popped up when I open Add Custom Node => I didn't checked the box next to `Custom` and chainID was empty as default value, I did that and it worked. I was using default checked next to `ETH` which was giving the error.

Comment: FYI, the chainId is the identifier for the chain. It was introduced in eip-155 to prevent replays on different chains. Ropsten is 3, eth is 1. If you have a custom ethereum chain, it would be whatever you set it up as.